# Should internal security tools use self signed certificates?

Tags: tls, certificates

I know of a company who has many internal security tools use for different functions within the company. Most if not *all* of the tools are using self signed certificates, and not certificates signed by a CA. Either they are internal or generated by the tool itself.

My questions is, is there an argument for getting valid certs for these internal security tools?

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing details. In some cases self-signed certificates are acceptable as a solution. The fact that certificates are not issued by a CA doesn't ultimately make them invalid.

Comment: there's UX arguments for it, and issued certs _ensure_ greater validity than self-rolled certs, eg. revocation.

Comment: Not a very clear question.  Totally depends on the security tool.

Answer (score 3):

If the certificates are invalid, users using the system will likely become accustomed to selecting *proceed anyway* on their browser warning which isn't advisable from a security perspective. Anything could be proxying the traffic and intercepting system credentials. If the credentials are integrated with a corporate authentication system, the credentials could be pretty useful. If the credentials are limited to a log system for example, someone could selectively clear logs while logged in as another individual.

You can install the system certificate, install other corporate certificates or install certificates from recognised CAs. People shouldn't be encouraged to ignore security warnings.

Answer (score 1):

If the users are knowledgeable users around the field of security, then they may choose to permanently trust the self-signed certificates on first access (Trust On First Use, just like SSH). This will prevent any Man-In-The-Middle attacks against to systems which they have previously connected to.

However, an internal attacker (or malware) could Man-In-The-Middle an initial connection and present their own certificate. As users are used to accepting and trusting these self-signed certificates, she would be likely to succeed in capturing credentials.

At the end of the day it depends on the "risk profile" of the organisation. If this deemed an unlikely risk (as in most organisations), then self-signed certificates would suffice. An alternative would be to effectively set up an internal Certificate Authority where certificates are issued to servers and signed by a root (or intermediate) certificate which all users trust. Such trust can be set by group policy (GPO) on Microsoft Active Directory networks.

Answer (score 0):

> My questions is, is there an an argument for getting valid certs for these internal security tools?

If these tools are used internally only, then you don't need a "real" cert. An intermediate step would be to generate a company- or department-wide CA root and add it to all the browsers/client systems used.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about security tools that have a web interface like Beef or proxy tools like ZAP or Burp.

Usually this tools are running locally and access them through a browser, in this case a self signed certificate is perfectly fine. The purpouse of a certificate signed by a trusted certificate authority is that you trust the CA, therefore you trust the certificates signed by them. As you have signed the tool's certificate yourself (I asume you trust yourself) you can always check that the certificate you see in the browser is the one you (Or the tool) made

If the tool is shared between multiple employees and you think this is a risk you can always create your own certificate authority, create a certificate for each tool and sign the new tool's certificate with it (Probably you will need to configure the new certificate). Then just install your CA in all the computers that need to access the tool and you won't have those messages again.

[Here is a guide to create your own CA](https://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/), just make sure you use a strong enough key